# Ruby class attributes not querying correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes

I have a class in my `Ruby on Rails` project for Institutions that I recently had to add an attribute to, an `:identifier`. The class has a custom metadata field that accompanies it for searching and indexing purposes. The problem is, the new attribute I added isn't helping me find objects the way I wanted. If I try to query for an object using the `:identifier` to do so I get consistently get an empty array. And yes, I have checked multiple times to ensure that the test object actually exists.

This is the model:

```
class Institution < ActiveFedora::Base
  include Hydra::AccessControls::Permissions

  # NOTE with rdf datastreams must query like so ins = Institution.where(desc_metadata__name_tesim: "APTrust")
  has_metadata "rightsMetadata", type: Hydra::Datastream::RightsMetadata
  has_metadata 'descMetadata', type: InstitutionMetadata

  has_many :intellectual_objects, property: :is_part_of

  has_attributes :name, :brief_name, :identifier, datastream: 'descMetadata', multiple: false

  validates :name, :identifier, presence: true
  validate :name_is_unique
  validate :identifier_is_unique


  def users
    User.where(institution_pid: self.pid).to_a.sort_by(&:name)
  end


  private

  def name_is_unique
    errors.add(:name, "has already been taken") if Institution.where(desc_metadata__name_ssim: self.name).reject{|r| r == self}.any?
  end

  def identifier_is_unique
    count = 0;
    Institution.all.each do |inst|
      count += 1 if inst.identifier == self.identifier
    end
    if(count > 0)
      errors.add(:identifier, "has already been taken")
    end
    #errors.add(:identifier, "has already been taken") if Institution.where(desc_metadata__identifier_ssim: self.identifier).reject{|r| r.identifier == self.identifier}.any?
  end

end
```

As you can see, I had to write a very different method to check for the uniqueness of an identifier because the `.where` method wasn't returning anything. I didn't realize that was the problem though until I started working on the show model in the controller (below):

```
def show
  identifier = params[:identifier] << "." << params[:format]
  @institution = Institution.where(desc_metadata__identifier_ssim: identifier)
end
```

This never returns anything even though I have several Institution objects in my database and have double and triple checked that the URL parameters are correct. And part of double checking that was searching for objects in the console. Here's the output:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.3)
2.0.0-p353 :001 > ap = Institution.where(desc_metadata__name_ssim: "APTrust")
ActiveFedora: loading fedora config from /Users/kec6en/HydraApp/fluctus/config/fedora.yml
ActiveFedora: loading solr config from /Users/kec6en/HydraApp/fluctus/config/solr.yml
Loaded datastream list for aptrust-dev:379 (3.2ms)
Loaded datastream profile aptrust-dev:379/RELS-EXT (2.7ms)
Loaded datastream content aptrust-dev:379/RELS-EXT (2.4ms)
Loaded datastream profile aptrust-dev:379/descMetadata (2.6ms)
Loaded datastream profile aptrust-dev:379/descMetadata (3.5ms)
Loaded datastream content aptrust-dev:379/descMetadata (3.1ms)
 => [#<Institution pid: "aptrust-dev:379", name: "APTrust", brief_name: "apt", identifier: "aptrust.org">] 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > apt = Institution.where(desc_metadata__identifier_ssim: "aptrust.org")
 => [] 
2.0.0-p353 :003 >
```

As you can see, I'm querying for an identifier that does exist but it's not finding anything. For reference, here is the metadata datastream that I'm working off of. Note that the identifier is indexed as `:stored_searchable` so I should be able to query for it.

```
class InstitutionMetadata < ActiveFedora::RdfxmlRDFDatastream
  map_predicates do |map|
    map.name(in: RDF::DC, to: 'title') { |index| index.as :symbol, :stored_searchable }
    map.brief_name(in: RDF::DC, to: 'alternative')
    map.identifier(in: RDF::DC, to: 'identifier') { |index| index.as :symbol, :stored_searchable }
  end
end
```

I modeled it after the name attribute because that one appears to be working. Any ideas why the identifier isn't?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the validation rails gives you. `validates :name, :identifier, presence: true, uniqueness: true` instead of creating your own unique check.

Comment: If you grab that `Institution` and do `institution.desc_metadata__identifier_ssim` what is returned?

Comment: Trying to grab it that way produces a `NoMethodError`. And I can't use the rails validator on this particular class. It produces an `Unknown Validator` error, I think because the Institution model isn't part of `ActiveRecord`, just `ActiveFedora`.

Comment: I should add that trying to grab the name that way also produces a `NoMethodError`. But If I try to grab either the name or the identifier by calling `institution.descMetadata.name` or `institution.descMetadata.identifier` I get the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `desc_metadata__identifier_tesim` instead of `desc_metadata__identifier_ssim` seems to work for finding objects, although it still doesn't work for the uniquess checking method I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just search the identifier directly instead of using the `desc_metadata`?

```
Institution.where identifier: "aptrust.org"
```

Comment: I've tried doing that as well with the same results. Nothing.